# How to implement random sampling of a set of vectors in java?

Tags: java, random, montecarlo, semantic-analysis

I have a huge number of context vectors and I want to find the average cosine similarity of them. However, it's not efficient to calculate it through the whole set. That's why, I want to take a random sample from this set.

The problem is that each context vector explains a degree of the meaning for a word so I want to make a balanced selection(according to vector values). I searched and found that I can use Monte Carlo method. I also found a Gibbs Sampler example here: https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/gibbs-sampler-in-various-languages-revisited/

However, I confused a little bit. As I understand, the method provides a normal distribution and generates double numbers. I did not understand how to implement this method in my case. Could somebody explain me how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define "balanced"? Similar number of each type of definition? Probability of selection based on type? Something else?

Comment: I mean some vectors defines stronger meaning for the target word while some others define weak. For example, if I mostly select from the weak ones, it will give me a wrong result while calculating the average cosine similarity. Let's say I will select 100 vectors among 2000, I want to pick from both stronger and weak vectors. An example for a stronger vector: (100,43,80,15) and for a weak vector: (2,0,10,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a *random* sample, you want a *representative* sample. One relatively efficient way to do this is to sort your elements in "strength" order, then take every nth element, which will give you a representative sample of size/n elements.

Try this:

```
// Given
Set<Vector> mySet;
int reductionFactor = 200; // eg sample 0.5% of elements

List<Vector> list = new ArrayList<>(mySet);
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Vector> {
    public int compare(Vector o1, Vector o2) {
        // however you compare "strength"
    }         
});
List<Vector> randomSample = new ArrayList<>(list.size() / reductionFactor );
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += reductionFactor)
    randomSample.add(list.get(i);
```

The time complexity is O(n log n) due to the sort operation, and space complexity is O(n).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

The program compiles and runs fine. It needs a jar file, or a "Java Archive" in order to compile and run. Specifically, it needs the ParallelColt library, a "a multithreaded version of Colt - a library for high performance scientific computing in Java." It can be found at this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/parallelcolt/). Once you have it, get the java JDK (SE version) from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Copy the source you referenced and the parallelcolt-0.9.4.jar file into a directory and compile and run with these commands:

```
javac -cp parallelcolt-0.9.4.jar Gibbs.java

java -cp parallelcolt-0.9.4.jar;. Gibbs
```

Note, you will probably need to include the compiler on your path. In windows I do it like so:

```
path="c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin";%PATH%
```

Please select this response as an answer if it helps you.

Comment: I've already import cern.jet.random package into my project and apply the code. As I said in my question, it creates a normal distribution and returns double numbers. I did not understand how to use Gibbs sampler in my case.

Comment: I don't know how to apply this code to your problem, sorry.